# Jenkins Cron Expression Not Scheduled at Right time

Tags: jenkins, cron

All,

Tried to configure jenkins job to trigger at EVERYDAY 10AM and used below cron `H 10 * * *` but the jenkins console is not running at 10AM rather its running at 10.09AM. Please help me to run at 10AM everyday around the year.

[image]

update: After adding the expression with '0 10 * * *', got below warning and no next run time is displayed. is that normal?[image]

Comment: H is used to reduce the load on the Jenkins server, so the build can be delayed for a few minutes.

Comment: @BrunoLavit proper term would be 'to balance the load' since that not actually 'reducing' it.

Comment: @Zloj Thanks for correcting my poor English ;) (FYI I can't edit my comment...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
30 5 * * *
```

will run every day at 5:30 AM

```
@daily
```

will run the job once a day at some time, chosen by Jenkins

```
0 10 * * *
```

will run every day at 10:00 AM

When not using 'H' in the beginning you *will* get the warning, you *will not* get a tip when the job will or would have run, but it *will* still be active, i.e. it will run as per the statement.

You will always see a syntax error in red color when making any syntax errors.
Also, a good idea might be to create a dummy job to experiment with cron trigger, if you don't feel comfortable with it yet. Or use crontab on Linux:

```
crontab -e
man crontab
```

Answer (score 3):

If you really want it at 10AM, please use `0 10 * * *`

or 5:30 AM as you asked in comment

```
30 5 * * *
```

Jenkins will warn you in this case. If every job schedules like this, load suddenly  goes up. Jenkins advice you to differ job time a bit.  The H indicate once in every hour, not particularly at 0th minute.

Comment: Tried that but got a warning "Spread load evenly by using ‘H 10 * * *’ rather than ‘0 10 * * *’ hence, added "H" in prefix

Comment: Correct.  That is _just a_ warning :) .   It your machine and decision after all.  You can schedule other jobs with H, but leave this one at 0 10...

Comment: ok, but am not seeing the next job run time when the focus is out? is that ususal?

Comment: I have updated answer. Please  do a quick reading on the cron format; that is pretty useful many other places