# Jenkins CRON Expression not triggering at right time

Tags: jenkins

how to add JENKINS CRON Expression for every Sunday 2 am .

I used expression like

```
     H  2  *  *  0
```

but it is triggering **@ 2:30am instead of 2am**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jenkins Cron Expression Not Scheduled at Right time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31518716/jenkins-cron-expression-not-scheduled-at-right-time)

Comment: 'H' is used to spread the load of jobs scheduled for the same time. You can read more about it in the help text of the cron trigger field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a job to build every Sunday at 2:00 AM exactly, you should use this syntax:

```
0 2 * * 0
```

i.e. at minute 0, of hour 2.

But in general when scheduling tasks with Jenkins, it's a good idea to use the `H` parameter in order to ensure that lots of jobs don't all start at exactly the same time, like on the hour.  Using `H` spreads out the load between jobs, to avoid overwhelming the server.

As you've seen, using `H 2 * * 0` may start at *any time* between 2 and 3 AM.  Though for one job, the execution time will remain the same, e.g. always 2:30.  Jenkins tells you below the cron textbox when it will execute next.

Comment: When i try 0 2 * * 0 , am getting below warning message : Spread load evenly by using ‘H 2 * * 0’ rather than ‘0 2 * * 0’

Comment: @KeepSmiling That's not an error message; it's just warning you that it's better to use the `H` syntax unless you _really_ want to schedule at an exact time. So you can ignore the warning, and your job will start at 2 AM.

Answer (score 0):

this is the correct format 0  2  *  *  0 ( the first `0` digit is the minute)

you can read some more at http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/

Thanks

Comment: when i try 30 2 * * 0 am getting this warning message :  Spread load evenly by using ‘H 2 * * 0’ rather than ‘30 2 * * 0’